# How to get selection Changed object value using wijmo grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, wijmo

Here i created  same directive for wijmo grid, here my problem is i am not able to get selected row value,how to do section changed in directive ? 
Thanks in advance

[sample code for wijmo grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ZHLGvi5HOTWSQLeS6mm?p=preview)

```
app.directive('customFlexGrid', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div/>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        itemsSource: '=',
        gridheader: '='      

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var grid = new wijmo.grid.FlexGrid(element[0]);

        scope.$watch('itemsSource', function () {

            grid.itemsSource = scope.itemsSource;
            grid.columns[1].width = 300;
            grid.selectionMode= "Row";
            grid.isReadOnly=true;

        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The grid's "selection" property returns a CellRange object that contains the selection. It's a get/set property, so you can use it at any time to find out what rows and columns are selected, or to modify the selection.

If a single cell is selected, the range's "row" and "col" properties will contain the indices of the selected row and column. If a range is selected, you can use the ranges "topRow", "leftCol", "bottomRow", and "rightCol" to get the range.

This link describes other useful methods and properties of the CellRange object:

https://wijmo.com/5/docs/topic/wijmo.grid.CellRange.Class.html